# Created an app to automatically post wordpress blog posts to facebook page - only I can see posts

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I have installed a plug-in called Simple Facebook Connect in Wordpress for my site, runtheworlds.com.  I had to create an app, put in the settings into the plug-in, and it's supposed to let me post blog posts on my facebook fan page:  https://www.facebook.com/runtheworlds

I've been able to see the post -- I can see it in my newsfeed and on the actual facebook fan page, but nobody else can see it.  I've checked the settings, and it appears to be posting as public, but nobody else can see the posts except for me.  Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-autosharepost/) ? It appears it hasn't been maintained in awhile. Additionally, there's a [paid plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sharepress/) which appears to be highly maintained.